# NotFoundHttpException after following link in email

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to learn Laravel 5.3, so I'm doing my own password reset. In a "reset email" link, I'm sending myself the following link:

`http://localhost:8000/users/newpassword/1/8ur7e1pvag6kx8nl0w`

In my routes file I have:

`Route::get('/users/newpassword/{$id}/{$remember}', 'UserController@newPassword')->name('usernewpassword');`

However when I click the link, I'm getting: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`

I'm running this via `artisan serve`, so the port part of the link is correct.

I've also created the following method in the Users controller:

```
public function newPassword($id, $remember) {
    return view('users.newpass');
}
```

Any ideas why this could be? Thanks!

Comment: Have you defined method `newPassword` in `UserController.php`?

Comment: @LionelChan Yes. I've updated my question with this info.

Comment: Class name is `UserController.php`? Namespace is `App\Http\Controllers`? You can also show us how have you defined your `web.php` route file. A route prefix could spoils the fun too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistake in route file. It should be like this

```
Route::get('/users/newpassword/{id}/{remember}', 'UserController@newPassword')->name('usernewpassword');
```

Instead of this:

```
Route::get('/users/newpassword/{$id}/{$remember}', 'UserController@newPassword')->name('usernewpassword');
```

More about route parameters:

[Laravel Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-parameters)